# iOS Sharing facebook open graph story as page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharing

I'm trying to find a way for facebook page admins to share as the page from my application. Example:

Facebook user "John Doe" owns the facebook page "John's cookies". John Doe logs to my app with facebook and publishes as "John's Cookies" from within my app.

Someone told me this is possible by exchanging user token for a page token, then use the page token for API calls, but I don't how to do this...

I have open graphs already working, I used facebook tutorials to implement it, but there's not such a thing as user token anywhere on the code...

Any help with this is highly appreciated.